# Spring Cloud Kinesis binder when kpl/kcl are enabled creates SpringIntegrationMetadataStore and SpringIntegrationLockRegistry. Is it necessary?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying Spring Cloud Kinesis binder with intention to use it in production. I want to rely on KCL/KPL channel adapters so I switched on kplKclEnabled property. My app still creates SpringIntegrationLockRegistry and SpringIntegrationMetadataStore tables. Is it necessary as we use KCL which already have created a metadata table with my consumer group name? If its not necessary, how can I switch it off ?